# I need to identify day, month and year selected in datetimepicker and validate the date

Tags: calendar, datetimepicker

I need to set up a calendar in datetimepicker with simple rules, day can't be less than 01, day can't be greater than 31, month can't be less than 01, month can't be greater than 12, year can't be less than 0001 and also identify the leap year to set February with 28 or 29 days.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which tool and programming language (if you know)? Your requirements are built in with most standard date pickers.